# Beep codes for late 2009 iMac

Tags: mac, boot, imac

My iMac beeps on startup. Does anyone know the beep codes?

I never actually knew what the beeps were, until I read "[How do I reset the time on my computer without turning it on?](https://superuser.com/questions/473464/how-do-i-reset-the-time-on-my-computer-without-turning-it-on)".

Answer (score 2):

> 1 tone, a 5-second pause, repeat – No RAM installed
>
> 3 successive tones, a 5-second pause, 3 successive tones – RAM does not pass data integrity check
>
> 1 long tone when holding down the power button – Firmware upgrade in process.
>
> 3 long tones, 3 short tones, 3 long tones – Firmware restoration from CD in process.

http://bamajr.com/2009/06/05/macintosh-post-beeps-defined-part-3/